# Failed to launch rospy file: SyntaxError: invalid syntax YAMLObject(metaclass=YAMLObjectMetaclass):

Tags: python, syntax-error, ros

So here is the full error:

```
$ rosrun turtlesim_cleaner1 rotate.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kwinklink/catkin_ws/src/turtlesim_cleaner1/src/turtlesim_cleaner1/rotate.py", line 2, in <module>
    import rospy
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/rospy/__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    from std_msgs.msg import Header
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ._Bool import *
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/std_msgs/msg/_Bool.py", line 5, in <module>
    import genpy
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/genpy/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . message import Message, SerializationError, DeserializationError, MessageException, struct_I
  File "/opt/ros/noetic/lib/python3/dist-packages/genpy/message.py", line 47, in <module>
    import yaml
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/yaml/__init__.py", line 399
    class YAMLObject(metaclass=YAMLObjectMetaclass):
                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here i have a picture of the error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8L1c.jpg)

I will appreciate any answers please help i have been workon on this error for a werry long time.
In my rotate.py i onli have`#!/usr/bin/env python import rospy`

Comment: That's rather strange. The error indicates that the program is launched with Python 2 interpreter which does not support this `metaclass` syntax. But the traceback also shows that the libraries are installed with the Python 3 which supports this syntax.

Comment: Yes, all i had to do was at the top of my script say #!/usr/bin/env python3 import rospy instead of #!/usr/bin/env python import rospy. Thanks!

Comment: @Kwinklink I had the same error. Changing to #!/usr/bin/env python3 worked for me too. You should post it as a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution!

Turns out all I had to do was to change **#!/usr/bin/env python import rospy**
To: **#!/usr/bin/env python3 import rospy**